# Selecting Minimum values from in_memory dataset!

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes, select, in-memory

I am trying to select the minimum value from a data set being stored in the `in_memory` workspace. This prevents me from using sub-queries. I'm hoping that someone has found a work around for this issue or something similar.

Comment: Welcome! Please take the tour (http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and update your question to let us know anything that you've tried so far and what results you received/any issues that you are having reaching your goals.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this Python snippet, if you're using ArcGIS 10.1 or later:

```py
fc = 'in_memory/dataset_name'
subquery = ''' YOUR SQL QUERY HERE '''
minval = min(r[0] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['FIELD_OF_INTEREST'], subquery))
print minval
```

Comment: This would require parsing the field for all rows. Wouldn't [Summary Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) on a layer (with the subquery applied as a definition query) be faster with a large feature class?

Comment: I don't see any reason why Summary Statistics would be faster. The `subquery` argument supplied to the `where_clause` parameter limits the cursor results to only the rows matching the query, which are exactly what Summary Statistics would have to process using your method. Unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: The issue is where the work is done -- in a binary or after processing a list with, say, 100k elements.  The I/O cost to write and read should be higher than a read which writes one row, then reading that row.